# How to get emails based on received date

Tags: c#, outlook

How to get emails from Outlook mail Item based on email received date?

```
using OutLook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; 
OutLook.Application outlookObj;
OutLook.NameSpace olintNS; 
OutLook.MailItem mailitem; 
mailitem = outlookObj.CreateItem(OutLook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

We want **mailitem** get only those mail received today.

Something like a filter on received date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the Inbox folder using `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)`, then call `MAPIFolder.Itenms.Restrict` on the `ReceivedTime` being in the range of, for example, 7/30/2016 and 7/31/2016.